# How to find the encoding of a python3 bytes object

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, decode

I know that `bytes.decode` gives a string and `string.encode` gives the bytes, but only if the correct `encoding` is used.

Suppose I have a bytes object encoded using `gb18030`
If I try to decode it using `big5`:

```
>>name = '深入 damon'
>>b1 = name.encode('gb18030')
>>> b1.decode('big5')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'big5' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 2: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Is there some way the encoding can be found from a `bytes` object?
I couldn't find any useful api in this regard in `python3`docs.

Comment: There isn't. If there was a general way of finding it, the decode function would not need its argument. The best you can get is educated guesses. The encoding is not part of the information contained in the bytes (unless you know are dealing with self-describing data, like HTML)), it is a property external to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) package. Read [this](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/case-study-porting-chardet-to-python-3.html) tutorial.

---

If you are using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-chardet
```

If you are using pip:

```
pip install chardet2
```

Comment: thanks @kev, I ran into the universaldetector import error ,but then your link to the dip3 case study helped..much obliged

Answer (score 4):

Since you've entered it from the console, the encoding will be `sys.stdin.encoding`

```
>>> name = '深入 damon'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'UTF-8'
>>> b1 = name.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
>>> b1
u'\u6df1\u5165 damon'
>>> b1.encode(sys.stdin.encoding)
'\xe6\xb7\xb1\xe5\x85\xa5 damon'
>>> print b1.encode(sys.stdin.encoding)
深入 damon
```